# Grep a number of bytes before match in binary files?

Tags: grep, binary

I often use `grep -ao ...word file.bin` to look up a text content ("word") and the few characters before it; as a reminder:

```
   -a, --text
          Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option.
   -o, --only-matching
          Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate
          output line.
```

Right; so just now, I realized that it behaves like this: I've tried first looking up the string `war` and one character before it:

```
$ grep -ao .war myfile.zip
/war
9war
$war
ʆwar
```

Ok, so I get 4 hits here. Now, if I want to look up looking up the string `war` and two more characters before it:

```
$ grep -ao ..war myfile.zip
>$war
```

So, now, for some reason, I get only one result?!

My guess is, the value of "two characters before" in the three missing cases is 0x00 (end of C string), so `grep` does not output that match - otherwise I would have still expected 4 results (unless the very first match previously was at start of file, otherwise I would have expected 3 results).

Can I somehow persuade `grep` to simply "ignore" null bytes in matches (or replace them with a dot or something) and still print matches that might have them? If not `grep`, is there another tool that could do this?

Comment: grep is line-based by default, so that `a\nbwar` is *not* matched by `..war`, as well.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to only show ASCII characters? Or do you want to check EVERY character before `war`? For instance, in the example @MarcusMüller provided, `a\nbwar`, would you like to show `\nbwar` or `abwar`? What is the purpose of your question?

Answer (score 4):

There are at least two (well three) problems with your approach.

Even with the non-standard `-o`, `grep` is line based, in that it finds all the matched to `o`utput on each line, lines being sequences of characters delimited by a newline character (byte with value 10 / 0x0a on ASCII-based systems).

So:

```
grep -o ..war
```

Will only return `war` instances that  follow 2 *characters* (not bytes which is one of the 3 issues here) other than newline.

For instance, on an input like `<0x0a>Xwar`, the 0x0a byte delimits the previous line, and the next line starts with `Xwar` where there's only one character before `war`.

In a UTF-8 locale, on an input like `<0xff><0xc3><0xa9>war`, the two bytes `<0xc3><0xa9>` form the `é` character, but the 0xff byte before it is invalid,  so can't form a character.

`grep` in general is only meant to work on text, so depending on the `grep` implementation, input with NUL characters or with overlong lines or not ending in newline characters could put a spanner in the works.

Then, in `xxwarwar`, `grep -o` will find `xxwar`, but resume search for more matches after that, so won't find `arwar`.

Those issues could be addressed by using `perl` and:

```
perl -l -0777 -ne 'print "$1$2" while m{(?<=(..))(war)}sg'
```

Where we find instances of `war` that are preceded by any 2 bytes (not characters in the user's locale), using a look-behind operator for those preceding bytes so as not consume the input. With `-0777`, which sets a record separator as something impossible, we work on the whole input as opposed to each line in the input.

Comment: +1 on the `-0777` part. I was looking for a similar solution, and couldn't think of something as elegant. Had to resort to `open` and `read` with 1 byte. Would have never thought providing a non-existing delimiter. I was wondering if that was a known "hack", or something you came up with.

Comment: @aviro, it's a well known and documented feature also called slurp mode. See `perldoc perlrun`. It's the equivalent of `$/ = undef`. Since perl 5.36, there's `-g` as an alias to it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method is to convert binary to hex and match:

```sh
hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X" " "' file.bin | grep -o ".. .. $(printf "war" | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X" " "')"
```

You need one `..`  for each byte `.` you want to match before the string. The downside is that it's slower than direct matches with grep or perl, and won't find the subsequent match in consecutive patterns like `warwar` as the perl solution

The result will be printed as hex values instead. If you want to print the result as string then convert the bytes back like this

```sh
hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X" " "' file.bin | \
    grep -o ".. .. $(printf "war" | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X" " "')" | \
    xargs -d '\n' -n 1 bash -c '<<<"$1" xxd -r -p -; echo' bash
```

However beware that `\n`, `\r` and many other control characters before the string will mess up the output

You can also make the search faster by not printing a space after each byte with the caveat that false positives may appear because the hex string matches in the middle of a byte. This way you'll match `..` instead of `..`  for each `.`

```sh
hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X" ""' file.bin | \
    grep -o "....$(printf "war" | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X" ""')" | \
    xargs -d '\n' -n 1 bash -c '<<<"$1" xxd -r -p -; echo' bash
```